# Impedir digitação de caractere, se o valor monetário for incorreto no delphi

Tags: delphi, regex, valor-monetário

Meu objetivo, usando Delphi 10.1, é comparar o texto digitado em um Edit, no momento da digitação de um novo caractere, se o texto formato após a digitação da tecla (que pode ser digitada no final, início ou meio do texto existente) ainda "seria" um valor monetário válido, permitindo apenas 2 casas decimais.

E caso o "futuro valor" não seja válido, impedir a digitação da tecla.

Sei que o **JvValidateEdit** ou **JvEdit** fazem quase isto, se impedir colar, mas eles permitem digitar quantas casas decimais desejar, e arredonda para o valor programado (Ex: 2) ao sair. Seria bom se eu conseguir limitar, tanto caracteres inválidos e as casas no momento da digitação.

A princípio pareceu fácil, comparei no evento **OnKeyPress** de um **TEdit**, usando uma fórmula minha para verificar se é um valor monetário válido, com até 2 casas decimais:

```
//stValor := Edit1.Text + Key;
if not IsValidMoeda_1(stValor) then
key = #0;
```

fórmula atual:

```
function isValidMoeda_1(Valor: string):Boolean;//Teste
begin
  Result:=False;

  if TRegEx.IsMatch(Valor, '^(?:[0-9]{0,14}|0)(?:,\d{0,2})?$') then
    begin
      Result:=True;
    end;

end;
```

Até pareceu funcionar, mas não funciona se a tecla for digitada no início, ou em qualquer local no meio do texto. Então pensei ser impossível, mas então, vi softwares que fazem isto, dando liberdade para quem for digitar, e apenas impedindo a tecla se a futura sequência for inválida.

Claro, existe a opção como bancos fazem: enviar a nova tecla digitada sempre para o final da string, ou ainda só permitir números no edit, e depois dividir o valor por 100, mas, ficaria meio invasivo para o que desejo.

Existe alguma maneira de pegar o novo texto para comparar, mas ainda em tempo de invalidar a tecla?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para funcionar em qualquer posição, você precisa verificar a posição do cursor e o tamanho da seleção:

```
function isValidMoeda(Valor: string): Boolean;
begin
  Result := TRegEx.IsMatch(Valor, '^(?:[0-9]{0,14}|0)(?:,\d{0,2})?$');
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
var
  p, l: integer;
  s: string;
begin
  p := Edit1.SelStart + 1;
  l := Edit1.SelLength;
  s := Edit1.Text;
  delete(s, p, l);
  insert(Key, s, p);
  if not isValidMoeda(s) then
    Key := #0;
end;
```

Comment: Perfeito Ricardo, até pensei em pegar a posição do cursor mas não conhecia estes comandos. Só uma melhorada acrescentando "if not (Key in [#8,#13]) then Key:=#0" para o backspace, jogar isto num JvEdit com a opção caPase=False e pronto.

Comment: Verdade, devia ter posto a exceção. Acho que pode incluir o tab (#9) na lista.